# Favored Class Bonus at 1st Level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

So, it doesn't seem entirely clear from the Core Rulebook: does one get the favored class bonus (+1 to hp or +1 skill) at first level? I wouldn't have thought so, but I notice that the Hero Lab Pathfinder character building tool interprets the rules so that you DO get the bonus at level one.  Is this true?

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5833/how-do-favored-classes-work-in-pathfinder

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Under section 4 of the [Character Creation Outline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/character-creation) it states "...and the choice of gaining a hit point or a skill rank each time a character gains a level (including his first level)..."

So, yes, the favored class bonus does apply at 1st level.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, a character gets the bonus at first level if they have chosen their first level's class as their favored class. (And why wouldn't they?)

This is according to Paizo: [Favored Classes](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes.html)

You really can't get more authoritative a source than that.

Answer (score 3):

When a player makes a character they choose that character's 'favored class' at first level. Any time they gain a level in that particular class the player can choose to take either +1HP or +1 skill point.  I'm not sure why Hero Lab would be calculating it differently.
If your race is Human it may be because Human's get +1 skill point per level regardless.

Comment: see the comment I added to my own question... it appears that Hero Lab is working correctly by granting you the favored class bonus at level one.