# How do prestige classes work for half-elves?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, prestige-class, half-elf

I am considering having a prestige class for my Half-elf Druid. I am aware that you can multi-class with a half-elf do I need to have my second class open for my prestige? What I wanted to do with my druid is become a Dragon Disciple. To do so I have to have my other class be Sorcerer. To me being able to turn into a dragon and utilize some of it's features is right in line with how I want my druid. If I have to use my other class to be my prestige that totally messes up my plans. Any clarification on this matter would be awesome. It is not very clear in the book when you can pick up a prestige class or if it counts as one of your classes when creating your character. Thank you!

I am starting out at a level 1. I am using Sorcerer to get the knowledge arcane skill which is required for Dragon Disciple. I also thought it would not interfere much considering you can cast magic spells as a druid.

Comment: Could you add more detail? What's your starting level?

Comment: You can multiclass with any class/race combination. It sounds like you are asking about how the 'favored class bonus' mechanic works for half-elfs with prestige classes. Is that accurate?

Comment: @ColinD I'm still new so I am not sure 100% but giving some light on that may not hurt. I was just wondering if it would count a multi or did it have special rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am aware that you can multi-class with a half-elf do I need to have my second class open for my prestige?

You can multiclass with any race, and you are never limited in the number of different classes that you can take.

In *Dungeons & Dragons* 3.5, which Pathfinder is based on, you took an XP penalty for having more than one base class unless they were within one level of one another (and your Favored Class didn't count). Prestige classes did not count towards this penalty. But Pathfinder ditched that rule (and completely changed how Favored Classes work).

> What I wanted to do with my druid is become a Dragon Disciple. To do so I have to have my other class be Sorcerer.

Correct, dragon disciple requires at least one level in sorcerer (or another spontaneous arcane class). It’s not your “other class,” though, it’s just a class you have a level in.

You can then take levels in dragon disciple. It does not improve *anything* about you being a druid, though it will (slowly) improve your sorcerer spellcasting. This will make you a very poor druid by the time you finish dragon disciple.

> To me being able to turn into a dragon and utilize some of it's features is right in line with how I want my druid.

A [dragon shaman archetype druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/dragon-shaman) will work far better than dragon disciple.

> I am using Sorcerer to get the knowledge arcane skill which is required for Dragon Disciple. I also thought it would not interfere much considering you can cast magic spells as a druid.

You don’t really need sorcerer for Knowledge (arcane), though it does get you a +3 bonus. Druids can meet the knowledge requirement for dragon disciple without problem. It’s the spellcasting requirement that you need a sorcerer level for.

Comment: +1 dragon shaman seems like the way to go to match the flavor the op wants.

Comment: Thank you this is very enlightening one question I have is with favored classes if I were to pick two with my half-elf ability I would or would not loose out on later upper spells for druids?

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Multitalented has nothing to do with spellcasting; Favored Class bonuses are a little extra HP or a few more skill points, or some other little bonuses, but they don't advance spellcasting. So you could have both druid and sorcerer as a Favored Class, which would get you some extra HP or skills, but your spellcasting would still suffer massively. I *really* suggest that dragon shaman archetype.

Comment: I was mainly just in general. If I were to have two favored classes would my advancement be slower in those areas as opposed to using them solo. If so how slow.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos When you take a level in anything that's not druid, your druid stuff does not advance. So if you are a druid 3, and you take a level of sorcerer, you still have the druid spellcasting of a druid 3, not of a druid 4, even though you are a 4th-level character. Favored Class does not come into play here at all.

Answer (score 5):

### You're getting Favoured Class confused with a restriction on multiclassing

Favoured class in pathfinder gives you a bonus (+1 HP or +1 Skillpoint) every time you take a level in the favoured class.  Some races have alternate options (like +1 evolution point per 4 levels in Summoner for a Half Elf) that replace that bonus.  It in *no way* makes you unable to take different classes.  If you take a class that isn't your favoured class, you simply don't receive the bonus.

Each level of a class is modular, so you can be a *Barbarian 1/Fighter 1/Druid 2/Sorcerer 1/Bard 3* if you want, and you'd be a Level 8 character overall (1+1+2+1+3).

Taking a Prestige class is a matter of fulfilling the pre-requisites and then taking the class like any other.

In your case, you need 1st level Arcane spells, 5 Skill Ranks in Kn: Arcana, and not to be a dragon (**Dragon Disciple** pre-reqs).  You can only get 5 Skill Ranks at level 5, so the first time you can enter the class will be at level 6.  You'll also need Arcane spells (druids cast Divine spells), so you'll need to either take a feat that grants an arcane spell (there are a few, from memory) or take a level of *Sorcerer* or *Wizard*.  Or, actually, Summoner.  *Summoner* seems to work better with Druid flavour than either Sorcerer or Wizard.

So you could enter as a *Druid 4/Summoner 1*, or a *Druid 4/Sorcerer 1*, and then take your first level of dragon disciple at level 6, so *Druid 4/Summoner or Sorcerer 1/Dragon Disciple 1*, then *Druid 4/Summoner or Sorcerer 1/Dragon Disciple 2* etc.

One hitch in your plan might be that **Dragon Disciple** only advances Arcane spellcasting, so you couldn't advance your Druid spells by taking the class.  If so, you could ask your GM about a homebrewed version - a **Forest Dragon Disciple** or something, which requires Divine spells instead of Arcane, and advances Divine spellcasting.  This is a very simple homebrew and should have absolutely no rules ramifications whatsoever.

Alternately, Summoners are very similar to Druids in some ways, especially with the **First Worlder** character archetype, which lets them use the *Summon Nature's Ally* spell instead of *Summon Monster*, gives them a more fey or animal themed *eidolon* and generally makes them more 'nature summoners'.  They still have Arcane spells, and so qualify for **Dragon Disciple**.

Either way, let me reiterate, **there is no restriction on having only '2 classes' in Pathfinder whatsoever in any way.  You can take as many classes as you have levels to spend, although, that might be weaker than sticking to one class and advancing it.**

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is legal. From a flavor perspective, it sounds interesting, but mechanically, I think it will perform poorly.

You will need to take at least one level in sorcerer because of the spontaneous level 1 arcane casting prereq on dragon diciple, not for the knowledge(Arcane) skill.  Anyone can put ranks into any skill. For sorcerers knowledge(arcane) is a class skill, which just provides a +3 trained bonus. The +3 does not contribute to the prestige class requirements.

A druid/dragon disciple combination clashes because the dragon disciple prestige class only progresses *arcane* spell casting. Druids are *divine* spell casters.  **Multiclassing spell casters is almost always undesirable because you lose access to higher leveled spells, which are incredibly important**

You can multiclass any number of times for any race and class combinations. I think you are getting caught up on the half-elf's *Multitalented* racial feature. This feature simply gives you access to multiple *favored classes*. [See this question/answers for more information.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5833/3358). Prestige classes can never be favored classes, so there is no conflict. You would pick sorcerer and druid.