# Favored class in Pathfinder "Advanced"

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The core rulebook says:

> Whenever a character gains a level in his favored class, he receives either + 1 hit point or + 1 skill rank. The choice of favored class cannot be changed once the character is created, and the choice of gaining a hit point or a skill rank each time a character gains a level (including his first level) cannot be changed once made **for a particular level.**

Question 1: Am I able to alternate HP and SP each level as I want?

And the Advanced Players Guide Favored class option for Human says:

> Instead of receiving an additional skill rank or hit point whenever they gain a level in a favored class, humans have the option of choosing from a number of other bonuses, depending upon their favored class. The following options are available to all humans who have the listed favored class, and unless otherwise stated, **the bonus applies each time you select the listed favored class reward**.

> Rogue: The human gains +1/6 of a new rogue talent.

To my understanding this means +1 rogue talent every 6 levels in that favored class.

Question 2: If I am able to alternate my choice of Bonus for favored class, with a human rogue can I choose the advanced option every 6 levels to gain an additional talent?

Example: Human rogue, Favored class: Rogue

- lvl 1 +1 SP
- lvl 2 +1 HP
- lvl 3 +1 HP
- lvl 4 +1 SP
- lvl 5 +1 HP
- lvl 6 +1 rogue talent (for having 6 levels in rogue)

Or, do I have to choose "+1/6 of a new rogue talent" for 6 lvls to gain an extra talent?

Comment: Asking for vague thoughts isn't allowed here. What *specific* problem can we help with?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton There are 2 highly specific questions here, I suspect the vague request for thoughts at the end doesn't actually signify anything.

Comment: Miniman, can you reformat the question such that the question becomes clear then, please? It seems that they can both be phrased part of a single question addressing the querent's specific problem.

Comment: I think this has two distinct questions which don't need to be asked together, and one should be asked separately in another question. I'm waiting for the edit cooldown period to remove everything for question #2 and advise on posting it separately, unless someone wants to beat me to it.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5833/how-do-favored-classes-work-in-pathfinder)

Comment: @Adeptus Thanks, that actually covers these questions in here. Gambit, could you check Adeptus's link and see if it answers either or both of your questions?

Comment: @doppelgreener Looks like it answers the first half (you can change which benefit you take each level) but not the second (which appears to be a misunderstanding of how the fractional favored class bonuses work and should probably be asked and answered in this question).